# Summation rules for approaching a constant raises to the power of i?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

i have to solve from the left hand side to the right,

$ \sum_{i=1}^n i5^i = \frac{5(4n5^n-5^n+1)}{16}$

my thought is to just convert both i's to

$\frac {n(n+1)}{2}$

then keep solving, but Im wondering if there are any summation tricks or formulas when i is in the exponent position?

Comment: You can't simply sum over each $i$ and substitute $n(n + 1)/2$ in, because it's $\sum_i(i 5^i)$, not $(\sum_i i) 5^{\sum_i i}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let for $x\ne1$ $$S=\sum_{i=1}^nix^i=x+2x^2+3x^3+\cdots+(n-2)x^{n-2}+(n-1)x^{n-1}+nx^n$$

$$xS=x^2+2x^3+3x^4+\cdots+(n-2)x^{n-1}+(n-1)x^n+nx^{n+1}$$

$$(1-x)S$$
$$=x+x^2(2-1)+x^3(3-2)+\cdots+(n-1-(n-2))x^{n-1}+(n-(n-1))x^n-nx^{n+1}$$

$$=-nx^{n+1}+\sum_{i=1}^nx^i$$

$$=-nx^{n+1}+\dfrac{x(1-x^n)}{1-x}$$

Answer (score 3):

It's not that simple...

First, note that:

$\begin{align*}
  \sum_{1 \le k \le n} z^k
    &= \frac{z (1 - z^n)}{1 - z} \\
  \sum_{1 \le k \le n} k z^k
    &= z \frac{d}{d z} \frac{z (1 - z^n)}{1 - z} \\
    &= \frac{z (1 - (n + 1) z^n + n z^{n + 1})}{(1 - z)^2}
\end{align*}$

Everything in sight is a polynomial or a rational function, no troubles there.  Replacing $z = 5$ gives:

$\begin{equation*}
   \sum_{1 \le k \le n} k \cdot 5^k
     = \dfrac{(20 n - 5) \cdot 5^n + 5}{16}
\end{equation*}$

The help of [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) with the algebra is gratefully acknowledged.

Comment: thank you so much this all makes sense, I just have 2 questions. 1, is that very first step you provided the structure for all constants raised to an exponent with summations? and 2, when you got to the second step, why do we have z time d/dz?

Comment: The first line is just the formula for a geometric sum. The second line is what happens when you differentiate it and then multiply it by $z$. Are you familiar with differential calculus? First, you get $\sum_{1 \le k \le n} kz^{k - 1} = \frac{d}{dz} \frac{z(1 - z^n)}{1-z}$. Then multiply by $z$ to get $\sum_{1 \le k \le n} kz^k = z \frac{d}{dz} \frac{z(1 - z^n)}{1-z}$.